# How to reset the html plain dialog when repoen in Angular 16

Tags: html, angular, modal-dialog, angular16

I am using html plain dialog element in angular with mat-button-toggle-group and I need to reset the selections when I close the dialog.

```
<button (click)="fildialog.showModal()"><mat-icon class="filter-icon" >filter_list</mat-icon></button>

    <dialog id="fildialog" #fildialog>
        <div class="fil-container" >
            <div>
                <div> 
                    <mat-button-toggle-group #filter="matButtonToggleGroup" [value]="locaFilter"  multiple (change)="onValueChange(filter.value)" >
                        <mat-button-toggle class="first-toggle-element" value="fly">Fly</mat-button-toggle>
                        <mat-button-toggle class="second-toggle-element" value="route">On Route</mat-button-toggle>
                        <mat-button-toggle class="third-toggle-element" value="water">Water</mat-button-toggle>
                    </mat-button-toggle-group>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="command-buttons-container">
                <button id="closebutton" type="reset (click)="closeClicked()">Close</button>
                <button id="applybutton" (click)="applyClicked()">Apply</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dialog>
```

In the typescript I will handle some logics before invoking apply & close methods of the dialog.
When I reopen the dialog I need to have the previous applied selections only. Let's say when user open first time I have "Fly" options as selected and then user selects all options and click the close button and open again it has to show only the "Fly" options as selected.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand all right, you have problems to save the settings which set by user. You have some options:

#### Memory (Ram)

*Build a simple Angular `Service` and hold the settings*

```
// Service
...
public mySettings: {all: boolean, flight: boolean} = { all: true, flight: false};

setSettings(all: boolean, flight: boolean) {
  this.mySettings = { all, flight }
}

getSettings() {
  return mySettings;
}

// Component
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

openDialog() {
  ....
  dialog.settings = this.myService.getSettings();
  // your logic..
  // dialog closed
  this.myService.setSettings(dialog.settings);
}
```

#### Use localStorage to hold data if browser refreshing, too

*Same szenario. You can use a service, too.*

```
// Service
setSettings(all: boolean, flight: boolean) {
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify({ all, flight });
}

getSettings() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
}

// Component same like before
```

#### Third way is to use a database and a backend

Here you can send a http request with Angulars `httpClient` and save the settings in a database. Load it every the the component with the dialog is loaded (`ngOnInit` as example)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I do the similar one with [value]="locaFilter" property but when I open again it was not using the values in the modal, instead it uses the previously choosed (state is maintained) values.

Comment: So... you need to show me your typescript code